# Books on Mechanics

Tags: classical-mechanics

I was wondering if any of you know the names of some good books that give an introduction to langrangian and hamiltonian mechanics. I've finished kleppner and kolenkows introduction to mechanics and now would like to proceed to something a little bit more advanced. I've tried "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics" by arnold but i find it a bit too impenetrable with its formality.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Classical-Mechanics-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/1292026553/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1400845762&sr=1-1&keywords=goldstein+mechanics

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations

Answer (score 1):

How about Landau's classical book?